# regex to strict check numbers in string

Tags: python, regex

Example strings:

1. I am a numeric string 75698
2. I am a alphanumeric string A14-B32-C7D

So far my regex works: `(\S+)$`

I want to add a way (probably look ahead) to check if the result generated by above regex contains any digit (0-9) one or more times?

This is not working: `(\S+(?=\S*\d\S*))$`

How should I do it?

Comment: Are you saying it can't contain the same digit twice?

Comment: It must contains one or more digit (0-9)

Comment: Are you aware that your regex also allows all sort of Unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look ahead is not necessary for this, this is simply :

```
(\S*\d+\S*)
```

Here is a test case :

http://regexr.com?34s7v

Answer (score 1):

permute it and use the `\D` class instead of `\S`:

```
((?=\D*\d)\S+)$
```

explanation: `\D  = [^\d]` in other words it is all that is not a digit.

You can be more explicit (better performances for your examples) with:

```
((?=[a-zA-Z-]*\d)\[a-zA-Z\d-]+)$
```

and if you have only uppercase letters, you know what to do. (smaller is the class, better is the regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '''
I am a numeric string 75698   \t
I am a alphanumeric string A14-B32-C7D
I am a alphanumeric string A14-B32-C74578
I am an alphabetic number: three
'''

import re  

regx = re.compile('\s(?=.*\d)([\da-zA-Z-]+)\s*$',re.MULTILINE)  

print regx.findall(text)  

# result  ['75698', 'A14-B32-C7D', 'A14-B32-C74578']
```

Note the presence of `\s*` in front of `$` in order to catch alphanumeric portions that are separated with whitespazces from the end of the lines.